# Raspberry Pi Zero W not responding

Tags: power, led, pi-zero-w

I bought it about a year ago and a few days ago I plugged it into my Mac with a micro USB. I did make the mistake of plugging into the USB port initially but it did respond.

For a while it worked i:e the LED lite up. However, when I connected a HDMI cable, the LED went out.

Since then there has been no sign of life. I did not smell anything burning from the Pi.

Have I managed to brick my Pi and if so is there any possibility of repairing it?

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense, and maybe you need to clarify. Is the case that: (1) You bought it a year ago,  but you haven't used it before and have only just got around to using it and plugging it in, or... (2) you bought it a year ago, using it regularly and it has been working fine, but now using the *same* power supply it fails to work? Has the power supply broken? Or are you solely trying to power the Pi from the computer's USB?

Answer (score 2):

If you are powering it from the computer, as you seem to imply, it is probably underpowered when you hook it up with a screen.

Try using a more powerful power supply, like a phone charger. It will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

As @Bex said you may need a more powerful power supply.

Or if that doesn't work you can try flashing the operating system again (this could only be done if you don't have anything important on the raspberry pi).